# How do I move an image (top-bottom) once it's already in a table?

Tags: html, css

I would like to position the instagram link towards the middle of the image that is beside it.

```
<div align="center">
  <table cellpadding="0" width="400" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
           <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/yourfanpage/12345678" target="_blank">
              <img src="http://www.liviocapalbo.com/img/instagram-icon_white.png" alt="" width="128" height="128" border="0"cellpadding="30" >
           </a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.myspace.com/yourpage" target="_blank">  
            <hr style="border: none; width: 200px; height: 550px; color: white; background: rgba(000,0,0,0.0);;margin: 0; padding: 0;"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td>
           <a href="http://twitter.com/yourtwitter" target="_blank">
             <img src="http://askreu.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/gradient_1600x1200.jpg" alt="Follow Us On Twitter" width="367" height="550" border="0">
           </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/lezakese/1/edit

Comment: apparently there are some problems with your markup, http://jsfiddle.net/yFEju/ shows them in red

Comment: Those errors are easy enough to fix. The <img> needs to be self closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to accomplish (specifically why you are wrapping an `<hr>` in an `<a>` tag), but I've added some borders to your code that will hopefully illustrate why the layout is as such.

If you could further explain what you're trying to accomplish I'll do my best to help you out. Can you maybe link to a pic or wireframe or something of how you want it to look?

http://jsbin.com/lezakese/3/edit

Comment: Ok I made the instagram logo black for better explanation. Now this  is how it  looks normally. http://postimg.org/image/drkdg86o9/ I want the black image moved. Like this:http://postimg.org/image/r34uhbbux/

Comment: Ah ok, now I understand. Try this: [http://jsbin.com/lezakese/5/edit](http://jsbin.com/lezakese/5/edit)

Comment: In that link I've included 2 ways of doing the padding. #1: use `padding-top` for the `td.top` to push the image down. #2: (currently used) giving the `td.top img` a `margin-top` top push it down.

Comment: You may also want to approach the `<a href="http://www.myspace.com/yourpage" target="_blank"><hr class="spacer"></a>` differently as that's not really a standard use. Also, I don't think it's valid to wrap an `hr` in an `a` (but don't quote me on that). But that's beside the point.